# datatables Multi Column search filter when reload refresh Page lose column values

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, multiple-columns

Hello i have **datatables** with **Multi Column search filter**
and Function **bstatesave** for save the search when reload the page
the problem when i'm reload page i'm **lose** the value input

how i can show the value in column when reload refresh The Page

Before Reload/refresh page

[image]

After Reload/refresh page

[image]

Comment: In my code, anytime a search is ran, I put it in localStorage.  When the pages reloads, I pull it out and apply it to the table.